# Counting subfolders of a folder

Tags: powershell, directory, temporary

I am trying to delete ASP .NET temporary files creating a PowerShell script. Until now, I managed to find under `C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Temporary .NET Files` files (not folders) older than 60 days and delete them. But my problem now is that under `C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Temporary .NET Files` there is a folder named `root`. This folder has only one subfolder. What I want is

- Count how many subfolders exist under root folder.
- If there is only one folder, do not do anything.
- If there are more than one, leaves the most recent folder and delete the others.

How could this be done with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurse into that root folder, filter the results for directories (items for which the `PSIsContainer` property is `$true`), and count the results:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\root' -Recurse |
  ? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
  Measure-Object |
  select -Expand Count
```

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can simplify that by calling `Get-ChildItem` with the parameter `-Directory`:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\root' -Recurse -Directory |
  Measure-Object |
  select -Expand Count
```

Comment: I ran the script but

`Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' $_.PSIsContainer '.
At C:\Users\Christos\Documents\cleanup.ps1:1 char:15
+  Get-ChildItem <<<<  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework*\v*\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root" -R ? { $_.PSIsContainer }
| Measure-Object | select -Expand Count
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: Sorry, I had typed incorrectly the command. Igonre the above comment. it worked.

Now, my problem is that under folder C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Temporary .NET, I have 7 subfolders as I have 7 sites on my IIS. How can I syntax the script (with a loop help) for each folder and if counts 0 or 1 do not do anyhting, otherwise delete folders.

For example, I have
C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Temporary .NET\root
C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Temporary .NET\site1
C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Temporary .NET\site2
C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Temporary .NET\site3

and count for root, site1, site2 and site3 folders.

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post a new question.

Comment: What I mean is that I wouldn't like to declare each subfolder manually in the script but these paths saved in a variable and for each one count how many subfolders exist and do the process I mentioned.

Comment: Sure, I will post new question.